# (Java) Trying to animate an arraylist of coins with a (working) animation class

Tags: java, android, animation, libgdx, 2d

I have a coin class which takes in an integer `numOfCoins`and an enum `LayoutType`, which can be linear or curved. A linear layout displays the coins in a straight line one after the other - we'll work with this since the method is small and straight forward.

My constructor looks like this:

```
public Coin(float xPos, float yPos, int numOfCoins, LayoutType layout) {
        setType(ObjectType.COIN);
        coinList = new ArrayList<Coin>(); // arraylist of coins
        setPos(xPos, yPos); // set starting position of coin(s)
        if (layout == LayoutType.LINEAR)) {
            linearLayout(); // display coins in a straight line
        } else if (layout == LayoutType.CURVE{
            curveLayout();
        }

}
```

And my `linearLayout()` method looks like this

```
public void linearLayout() {
        //draw numOfCoins amount of coins in a straight line
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfCoins; i++) {
            Coin coin = new Coin(xPos, yPos);
            coinList.add(coin);
            xPos += 50; // place coins 50 pixels apart 
        }
}
```

I have a working animation class and a spritesheet for the coins - however, the way I have modelled my coins is in such a way that 1 coin object can contain `numOfCoins` amount of coins, so I can't just directly call the animation in the draw method.

The class' `draw()` method is in an abstract class `GameObject` which `Coin` extends. It looks like this:

```
public void draw(SpriteBatch batch) {
    // if the object is a coin iterate through the list of coins
    // and draw the sprites, if it isn't a coin, simply draw the objects sprite
    if (type == ObjectType.COIN) {
        for (Coin coin : getCoinList()) {
            coin.getCoinList().draw(batch);
        }
    } else {
        sprite.draw(batch);
    }
}
```

This draw() method is called in World.render().

How would I create an animation for each coin if I have 6 coins in a straight line for instance? I can't seem to find a way. Highly grateful for any help, thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with how to populate the Animation class with an array of TextureRegions? (from the documentation)

Comment: Yes, this is what my Animation class currently does. Other objects like player and enemy I can just call Animator.render() in their draw() method but the problem with this one is that one coin class can contain like 7-8 different coins so I'm not sure how to do it

Comment: I started writing an answer, but then I got completely confused by your class structure. Coin is a class that cointains a list of Coins. I guess the Coins that the upper level Coin contains leave their own ArrayLists unused? This is going to get really convoluted when individual coins from the group are collected, but others still remain.  Why not have a separate class for a CoinGroup?Also, is the draw method you showed above the draw method of the Coin class, or of the Game or Screen class?

Answer (score 2):

I got confused by your class structure (Coins owning lists of Coins). I would create a separate class for groups of coins.

```
public class Coin {
    Vector2 position;

    public Coin (float x, float y){
        position = new Vector2(x, y);
    }
}

public class CoinGroup extends GameObject {
    // This would be very similar to your current Coin class, and contain a list of 
    // the new Coins.
}
```

Give the CoinGroup class a reference to the Animation that will be shared by all its items, as well as a float variable to keep track of elapsed time.

```
Animation coinAnimation;
float elapsedTime;

public CoinGroup(float xPos, float yPos, int numOfCoins, LayoutType layout,
            Animation coinAnimation) {
        setType(ObjectType.COIN);
        coinList = new ArrayList<Coin>(); // arraylist of coins
        setPos(xPos, yPos); // set starting position of coin(s)
        if (layout == LayoutType.LINEAR)) {
            linearLayout(); // display coins in a straight line
        } else if (layout == LayoutType.CURVE{
            curveLayout();
        }
        this.coinAnimation = coinAnimation;
}
```

Then you need to update the elapsed time on each frame to use for the animation. You might already have some kind of update method you could stick this in, but if you don't, it would be something like this:

```
public void update (float deltaTime){
    elapsedTime += deltaTime;
}
```

The game or screen class needs to call `update` on the CoinGroup once each frame.

Then you can draw each of the coins by referencing that same animation. I didn't understand what was going on in you draw method (why would a coin's draw method need to check if it's a coin?), but this is the general idea.

```
public void draw(SpriteBatch batch) {
    TextureRegion coinFrameRegion = coinAnimation.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime);
    for (Coin coin : coinList){
        Vector2 coinPosition = coin.position;
        batch.draw(coinFrameRegion , coinPosition.x, coinPosition.y);
    }
}
```

If you want to get fancy, you can stagger the animation.

```
static final float ANIMATION_STAGGER = 0.15f;

public void draw(SpriteBatch batch) {
    for (int i=0; i<coinList.size; i++){
        Vector2 coinPosition = coin.position;
        batch.draw(coinAnimation.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime + i*ANIMATION_STAGGER ), coinPosition.x, coinPosition.y);
    }
}
```